# Add template conditionally in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some data:

```
$scope.posts = [ 
    { 'name' : 'post1', 'templateName' : 'template1.html' }, 
    { 'name' : 'post2', 'templateName' : 'template2.html' }
]
```

...and I have two templates:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template1.html">
   <p><span>{{post.name}}</p></li>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template2.html">
   <p>{{post.name}}</p>
</script>
```

They are to be inserted into a list that is backed by `$scope.posts`, which in turn is listed with:

```
<li ng-repeat="post in posts"></li>
```

How do I iterate over `$scope.posts` and insert the right template, based on `'templateName'`, but also populate it with `post.name`?

Answer (score 1):

I would use [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) for something like this, you can also use [ngSwitch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)

```
<p ng-if="post.templateName == myTemplate"></p>
<p ng-if="post.templateName == myOtherTemplate"></p>
```

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but I'm actually not even at that stage yet. I can't figure out how to actually compile the template. The <li> items only print out the HTML text of the templates, and not the rendered version of them. 

Do I need to compile them beforehand somehow?
The way I get the templates is:
$templateCache.get(post.templateName) – which only results in printing out the HTML string

Comment: Your answer looks good, more of a typical angular way to do it opposed to the first solution you posted.

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up doing the following:

```
<li ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <ng-include src="post.template"></ng-include>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to be safe:

```
<li ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <div ng-include="post.templateName"></div>
</li>
```

In case some Browsers(IE) don't like non standard tags.